# How to get the deleted item (for post-handling by proxy) if `length` property of array was decreased directly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-proxy

JavaScript (ECMAScript 6)

I wrote a proxy for `Array` item. I do it for solving the problem... I show this problem on the base of such example:

```
function Node(value){
  this.parent = null; // parent Node item
  this.value = value;
  this.children = []; // child Node items
}
```

I want each item of `children` array will  update own `parent` property when the item would be added into that array or removed from it.

Below is located my decision with unit tests. *I appologize for Russian comments (you can translate with [google translate](https://translate.google.com) those that are of interest to you)*.

Also I placed my code on jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Andrey_Bushman/e8qvwa7v/) (this resource shows code row numbers).

You can see one of my tests is failed... This is happen when I remove item by direct decreasing the `length` property of array. I see `deleteProperty` handler doesn't catch this event.

I.e. I my problem is exists for such variant of item deleting:

```
myarray.length -= 1;
```

At this case last item will be removed from array but its `parent` property will not be updated to `null` value.

How can I catch such case by the proxy?

Thank you.

```js
/* This is the module which I test. My QUnit tests start with code row 118. 
The failed test is on the code row 351.*/
(function(exports){

    /* Массив, автоматически управляющий ссылками на родителя для всех своих
     * дочерних элементов при их добавлении или удалении.
     *
     * propName - имя свойства, которое автоматически должно появляться и
     * обновляться у каждого элемента массива.
     *
     * parent - ссылка на объект, который должен быть указан в качестве значения
     * свойства, имя которого указано в propName у каждого элемента массива.
     *
     * ВНИМАНИЕ!
     * Если удалять элементы из хвоста прокси-массива посредством назначения
     * свойству length меньшего значения, то у удалённых таким образом элементов
     * свойство, подлежащее мониторингу, НЕ обновит своё значение! Поэтому не
     * следует пользоваться таким способом удаления элементов из прокси-массива,
     * полученного при помощи ArrayWithParentLink. Вместо этого используйте
     * методы pop(), shift() и splice().
     */
    exports.ArrayWithParentLink = function(propName, parent){

        /** Выяснение того, является ли ключ корректным индексом массива.
         * Вычисление выполняется в соответствии со спецификацией ECMAScript 6.
         * См. книгу "ECMAScript 6 для разработчиков" Николаса Вирта, стр. 307.
         * */
        function isArrayIndex(key){
            const toUint32 = function(value){
                return Math.floor(Math.abs(Number(value))) % Math.pow(2,32);
            };

            let numericKey = toUint32(key);
            return String(numericKey) == key && numericKey < (Math.pow(2,32)-1);
        };

        /* Редактирование состава вложенного массива будем выполнять через
         * прокси, дабы автоматизировать синхронизацию значения свойства,
         * имя которого было ранее указано в propName при создании экземпляра
         * прокси-массива. */
        var arrayChangeHandler = {

            set: function(target, key, value, receiver) {

                /* Если имя свойства является допустимым индексом массива,
                 * значит выполняется операция над элементом массива... */
                if(isArrayIndex(key)){

                    value[propName] = parent;

                    /* Очистить значение свойства (имя которого указано в
                     * propName) у заменяемого элемента, если в массиве на него
                     * имеется только одна ссылка. В некоторые моменты в массиве
                     * может присутствовать одновременно несколько ссылок на
                     * один и тот же элемент. Пример такого случая приведён в
                     * комментарии ниже.*/
                    if((key in target) && target[key] &&
                        (propName in target[key])){

                        /* Если выполняется ВСТАВКА новых элементов методом
                         * Array.prototype.splice(), то происходит добавление к
                         * массиву необходимого количества дополнительных ячеек,
                         * в которые записываются ссылки на уже существующие
                         * элементы массива, а их прежние ячейки переписываются
                         * ссылками на вставляемые элементы. Т.е. до того, как
                         * произойдёт перезапись, в составе массива временно
                         * присутствует ДВЕ ссылки на смещаемый элемент. Если не
                         * учесть этот момент, то свойству parent перемещаемого
                         * дочернего элемента будет назначено значение null, что
                         * будет являться неправильным действием. Чтобы избежать
                         * этой ошибки, проверяем количество ссылок на удаляемый
                         * объект. Если их более одной, то считаем, что
                         * происходит не удаление, но перемещение элемента в
                         * массиве: */
                        let linksCount = 0;

                        for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++){

                            if(target[i] == target[key])
                                linksCount++;
                        }

                        if(1 == linksCount)
                            target[key][propName] = null;
                    }
                }

                return Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver);
            },
            deleteProperty: function(target, key) {

                /* Если имя свойства является допустимым индексом массива,
                 * значит выполняется операция над элементом массива... */
                if(isArrayIndex(Number(key))){

                    /* ВНИМАНИЕ! Прочти комментарий перед аналогичной строкой
                     * кода для сеттера set, объявленого выше, дабы понимать,
                     * для чего выполняется проверка количества ссылок. */
                    let linksCount = 0;

                    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++){

                        if(target[i] == target[key])
                            linksCount++;
                    }

                    if(1 == linksCount)
                        target[key][propName] = null;
                }
                return Reflect.deleteProperty(target, key);
            }
        };
        return new Proxy([], arrayChangeHandler);
    };

})(window.Services = Object.create(null));

QUnit.module('Services.ArrayWithParentLink');

/** Проверка всех элементов прокси-массива.
 *
 * Это дополнительная проверка, которая используется в тестах, дабы убедиться в
 * том, что помимо ожидаемых изменений не произошли изменения неожиданные,
 * затрагивающие другие элементы, имеющиеся в прокси-массиве.
 *
 * array - прокси-массив, подлежащий проверке.
 * propName - имя свойства, проверяемого у элементов прокси-массива.
 * value - ожидаемое значение свойства, имя которого указано в propName.
 * assert - ссылка на объект assert фреймворка QUnit.
 * */
function checkAllItems(array, propName, value, assert) {
    // Проверим, что все элементы массива имеют правильное значение подлежащего
    // мониторингу свойства.
    let rightValues = true;

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i][propName] != value){
            rightValues = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    assert.ok(rightValues, "Каждый элемент в прокси-массиве содержат правильное"
    + " значение в свойстве, подлежащем мониторингу.");
}

QUnit.test( "Новый прокси-массив является обёрткой над экземпляром Array.",
    function( assert ) {

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);

    assert.ok(root.items instanceof Array);
});

QUnit.test( "Длина нового прокси-массива равна нулю.", function( assert ) {

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);

    assert.equal(root.items.length, 0);
});

QUnit.test( "В новом элементе, добавленном в прокси-массив при помощи метода" +
    "'push()', автоматически появляется подлежащее мониторингу свойство, " +
    "инициализированное правильным значением. ",
    function( assert ) {

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);

    root.items.push({});

    assert.equal(root.items[0][name], root);

    // Дополнительная проверка
    checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
});

QUnit.test( "В новом элементе, добавленном в прокси-массив при помощи индекса" +
    " [index], автоматически появляется подлежащее мониторингу свойство, " +
    "инициализированное правильным значением. ",
    function( assert ) {

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);

        root.items[0] = {};

        assert.equal(root.items[0][name], root);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
    });

QUnit.test("Метод 'pop()' прокси-массива успешно удаляет последний элемент.",
    function(assert){

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
        const count = 5;

        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
            root.items[i] = {};
        }

        const item = root.items[count - 1];
        const item2 = root.items.pop();

        assert.equal(item2, item);
        assert.equal(root.items.length, count - 1);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
});

QUnit.test("У удаляемого методом 'pop()' объекта, значение подлежащего "
    + " мониторингу свойства автоматически становится равным null, если в " +
    "массиве имелась только одна ссылка на удаляемый объект.",
    function(assert){

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
        const count = 5;

        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
            root.items[i] = {};
        }

        let item = root.items.pop();

        assert.equal(item[name], null);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
    });

QUnit.test("У удаляемого методом 'pop()' объекта, значение подлежащего "
    + " мониторингу свойства не изменяется на null, если в " +
    "массиве имелось более одной ссылки на удаляемый объект.",
    function(assert){

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
        const count = 2;
        const obj = {};

        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
            root.items[i] = obj;
        }

        let item = root.items.pop();

        assert.equal(item[name], root);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
    });

QUnit.test( "В новом элементе, добавленном в прокси-массив при помощи метода" +
    " 'unshift()', автоматически появляется подлежащее мониторингу свойство, " +
    "инициализированное правильным значением. ",
    function( assert ) {

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);

        root.items.unshift({});

        assert.equal(root.items[0][name], root);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
    });

QUnit.test("Метод 'shift()' успешно удаляет первый элемент прокси-массива.",
    function(assert){

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
        const count = 5;

        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
            root.items[i] = {};
        }

        const item = root.items[0];
        const item2 = root.items.shift();

        assert.equal(item2, item);
        assert.equal(root.items.length, count - 1);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
    });

QUnit.test("У удаляемого методом 'shift()' объекта, значение подлежащего "
    + " мониторингу свойства автоматически становится равным null, если в " +
    "массиве имелась только одна ссылка на удаляемый объект.",
    function(assert){

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
        const count = 5;

        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
            root.items[i] = {};
        }

        let item = root.items.shift();

        assert.equal(item[name], null);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
    });

QUnit.test("У удаляемого методом 'shift()' объекта, значение подлежащего "
    + " мониторингу свойства не становится равным null, если в " +
    "массиве имелось более одной ссылки на удаляемый объект.",
    function(assert){

        const root = Object.create(null);
        const name = 'parent';
        root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
        const count = 2;
        const obj = {};

        for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
            root.items[i] = obj;
        }

        let item = root.items.shift();

        assert.equal(item[name], root);

        // Дополнительная проверка
        checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
    });

QUnit.test("Значение подлежащего мониторингу свойства у элемента, удаляемого " +
    "посредством уменьшения значения свойства length массива, становится "
    + "равным null, если в массиве имелось не более одной ссылки на удаляемый "
    + "элемент", function(assert){

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
    const count = 2;

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        root.items[i] = {};
    }

    let item = root.items[count - 1];
    root.items.length = 1;

    assert.equal(item[name], null);

    // Дополнительная проверка
    checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
});

QUnit.test("Значение подлежащего мониторингу свойства у элемента, удаляемого " +
    "посредством уменьшения значения свойства length массива, не становится "
    + "равным null, если в массиве имелось более одной ссылки на удаляемый "
    + "элемент", function(assert){

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
    const count = 2;
    const obj = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        root.items[i] = obj;
    }

    let item = root.items[count - 1];
    root.items.length = 1;

    assert.equal(item[name], root);

    // Дополнительная проверка
    checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
});

QUnit.test("Значение подлежащего мониторингу свойства у элемента, удаляемого " +
    "посредством метода 'splice()', становится равным null, если в массиве " +
    "имелось не более одной ссылки на удаляемый элемент", function(assert){

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
    const count = 3;

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        root.items[i] = {};
    }

    const index = 1;

    let item = root.items[index];
    root.items.splice(index,1);

    assert.equal(item[name], null);

    // Дополнительная проверка
    checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
});

QUnit.test("Значение подлежащего мониторингу свойства у элемента, удаляемого " +
    "посредством метода 'splice()', не становится равным null, если в массиве "
    + "имелось более одной ссылки на удаляемый элемент", function(assert){

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
    const count = 3;
    const obj = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        root.items[i] = obj;
    }

    const index = 1;

    let item = root.items[index];
    root.items.splice(index,1);

    assert.equal(item[name], root);

    // Дополнительная проверка
    checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
});

QUnit.test("Значение подлежащего мониторингу свойства у элемента, добавляемого "
    + "в прокси-массив посредством метода 'splice()', инициализируется " +
    "правильным значением.", function(assert){

    const root = Object.create(null);
    const name = 'parent';
    root.items = new window.Services.ArrayWithParentLink(name, root);
    const count = 3;

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        root.items[i] = {};
    }

    const index = 1;
    const obj = {};
    root.items.splice(index,0,obj);

    assert.equal(obj[name], root);

    // Дополнительная проверка
    checkAllItems(root.items, name, root, assert);
});
```

```css
/*!
 * QUnit 2.3.3
 * https://qunitjs.com/
 *
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2017-06-02T14:07Z
 */

/** Font Family and Sizes */

#qunit-tests, #qunit-header, #qunit-banner, #qunit-testrunner-toolbar, #qunit-filteredTest, #qunit-userAgent, #qunit-testresult {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue", Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#qunit-testrunner-toolbar, #qunit-filteredTest, #qunit-userAgent, #qunit-testresult, #qunit-tests li { font-size: small; }
#qunit-tests { font-size: smaller; }


/** Resets */

#qunit-tests, #qunit-header, #qunit-banner, #qunit-filteredTest, #qunit-userAgent, #qunit-testresult, #qunit-modulefilter {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


/** Header (excluding toolbar) */

#qunit-header {
 padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;

 color: #8699A4;
 background-color: #0D3349;

 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1em;
 font-weight: 400;

 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#qunit-header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #C2CCD1;
}

#qunit-header a:hover,
#qunit-header a:focus {
 color: #FFF;
}

#qunit-banner {
 height: 5px;
}

#qunit-filteredTest {
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
 color: #366097;
 background-color: #F4FF77;
}

#qunit-userAgent {
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #2B81AF;
 text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 2px 2px 1px;
}


/** Toolbar */

#qunit-testrunner-toolbar {
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
 color: #5E740B;
 background-color: #EEE;
}

#qunit-testrunner-toolbar .clearfix {
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}

#qunit-testrunner-toolbar label {
 display: inline-block;
}

#qunit-testrunner-toolbar input[type=checkbox],
#qunit-testrunner-toolbar input[type=radio] {
 margin: 3px;
 vertical-align: -2px;
}

#qunit-testrunner-toolbar input[type=text] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 1.6em;
}

.qunit-url-config,
.qunit-filter,
#qunit-modulefilter {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 2.1em;
}

.qunit-filter,
#qunit-modulefilter {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 1em;
}

.qunit-url-config label {
 margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-search {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 400px;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-search-container:after {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0.3em;
 content: "\25bc";
 color: black;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown {
 /* align with #qunit-modulefilter-search */
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 400px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: 0.8em;

 border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
 border-top: none;
 border-radius: 0 0 .25em .25em;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 z-index: 99;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown .clickable.checked {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #D2E0E6;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown .clickable:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #0D3349;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-actions {
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;

 /* align with #qunit-modulefilter-dropdown-list */
 font: smaller/1.5em sans-serif;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown #qunit-modulefilter-actions > * {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 max-height: 2.8em;
 display: block;
 padding: 0.4em;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown #qunit-modulefilter-actions > button {
 float: right;
 font: inherit;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown #qunit-modulefilter-actions > :last-child {
 /* insert padding to align with checkbox margins */
 padding-left: 3px;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown-list {
 max-height: 200px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 margin: 0;
 border-top: 2px groove threedhighlight;
 padding: 0.4em 0 0;
 font: smaller/1.5em sans-serif;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown-list li {
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#qunit-modulefilter-dropdown-list .clickable {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 0.15em;
}


/** Tests: Pass/Fail */

#qunit-tests {
 list-style-position: inside;
}

#qunit-tests li {
 padding: 0.4em 1em 0.4em 1em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

#qunit-tests > li {
 display: none;
}

#qunit-tests li.running,
#qunit-tests li.pass,
#qunit-tests li.fail,
#qunit-tests li.skipped,
#qunit-tests li.aborted {
 display: list-item;
}

#qunit-tests.hidepass {
 position: relative;
}

#qunit-tests.hidepass li.running,
#qunit-tests.hidepass li.pass:not(.todo) {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 width:   0;
 height:  0;
 padding: 0;
 border:  0;
 margin:  0;
}

#qunit-tests li strong {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#qunit-tests li.skipped strong {
 cursor: default;
}

#qunit-tests li a {
 padding: 0.5em;
 color: #C2CCD1;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#qunit-tests li p a {
 padding: 0.25em;
 color: #6B6464;
}
#qunit-tests li a:hover,
#qunit-tests li a:focus {
 color: #000;
}

#qunit-tests li .runtime {
 float: right;
 font-size: smaller;
}

.qunit-assert-list {
 margin-top: 0.5em;
 padding: 0.5em;

 background-color: #FFF;

 border-radius: 5px;
}

.qunit-source {
 margin: 0.6em 0 0.3em;
}

.qunit-collapsed {
 display: none;
}

#qunit-tests table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin-top: 0.2em;
}

#qunit-tests th {
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 0 0.5em 0 0;
}

#qunit-tests td {
 vertical-align: top;
}

#qunit-tests pre {
 margin: 0;
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

#qunit-tests del {
 color: #374E0C;
 background-color: #E0F2BE;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#qunit-tests ins {
 color: #500;
 background-color: #FFCACA;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*** Test Counts */

#qunit-tests b.counts                       { color: #000; }
#qunit-tests b.passed                       { color: #5E740B; }
#qunit-tests b.failed                       { color: #710909; }

#qunit-tests li li {
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 border-bottom: none;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

/*** Passing Styles */

#qunit-tests li li.pass {
 color: #3C510C;
 background-color: #FFF;
 border-left: 10px solid #C6E746;
}

#qunit-tests .pass                          { color: #528CE0; background-color: #D2E0E6; }
#qunit-tests .pass .test-name               { color: #366097; }

#qunit-tests .pass .test-actual,
#qunit-tests .pass .test-expected           { color: #999; }

#qunit-banner.qunit-pass                    { background-color: #C6E746; }

/*** Failing Styles */

#qunit-tests li li.fail {
 color: #710909;
 background-color: #FFF;
 border-left: 10px solid #EE5757;
 white-space: pre;
}

#qunit-tests > li:last-child {
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

#qunit-tests .fail                          { color: #000; background-color: #EE5757; }
#qunit-tests .fail .test-name,
#qunit-tests .fail .module-name             { color: #000; }

#qunit-tests .fail .test-actual             { color: #EE5757; }
#qunit-tests .fail .test-expected           { color: #008000; }

#qunit-banner.qunit-fail                    { background-color: #EE5757; }


/*** Aborted tests */
#qunit-tests .aborted { color: #000; background-color: orange; }
/*** Skipped tests */

#qunit-tests .skipped {
 background-color: #EBECE9;
}

#qunit-tests .qunit-todo-label,
#qunit-tests .qunit-skipped-label {
 background-color: #F4FF77;
 display: inline-block;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #366097;
 line-height: 1.8em;
 padding: 0 0.5em;
 margin: -0.4em 0.4em -0.4em 0;
}

#qunit-tests .qunit-todo-label {
 background-color: #EEE;
}

/** Result */

#qunit-testresult {
 color: #2B81AF;
 background-color: #D2E0E6;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#qunit-testresult .clearfix {
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}
#qunit-testresult .module-name {
 font-weight: 700;
}
#qunit-testresult-display {
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
 width: 85%;
 float:left;
}
#qunit-testresult-controls {
 padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  width: 10%;
 float:left;
}

/** Fixture */

#qunit-fixture {
 position: absolute;
 top: -10000px;
 left: -10000px;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.3.3.js"></script>
```

**UPD**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Andrey_Bushman/e8qvwa7v/1/) is my fixed variant. It works.

Comment: Without digging into your code, maybe sth like if(key==="length"){ for(var i=0;i<value-target[key];i++) var removed=target.pop();}

Comment: This property will be changed also when be done `shift()` or deleting by `splice()`. I.e. removed item not always is in the tail of array, but event of changing the `length` property will happen at each of these case.

Comment: apply another rule for splice and shift..

Comment: @Jonasw, I'm not agree with you. I haven't problem with `splice()` and `shift()` methods. In addition, the code was specified by you above in your comment does not make sense.

Comment: @Jonasw, I apologize. I didn't understand your code at first. You are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could listen to changes of the *length* property, and remove the elements manually:

```
set(key,value,target){
 if(key==="length"){ 
  for(var i=0;i<value-target[key];i++){
   var removed=target.pop();
   ///change removed...
  } 
 return;
 }
 //change target[key]
}
```

Comment: I understood your idea, but did not use pop to avoid looping.

Comment: Here is my fixed variant: https://jsfiddle.net/Andrey_Bushman/e8qvwa7v/1/